# Rviz crash when adding topic

Tags: ros, rviz, pointcloud, artificial-intelligence, rviz-plugins

I'm using a plugin for visualization of topic type [vision_msgs/Detection3DArray](https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/vision_msgs/html/msg/Detection3DArray.html). I add a point cloud and there is not problem, but when I add this topic Rviz crashes with this error message:

```
original visual, set by message: position Vector3(0, 0, 0) with orientation Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0)
rviz: /build/ogre-1.9-kiU5_5/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/include/OgreAxisAlignedBox.h:251: void Ogre::AxisAlignedBox::setExtents(const Ogre::Vector3&, const Ogre::Vector3&): La declaración `(min.x <= max.x && min.y <= max.y && min.z <= max.z) && "The minimum corner of the box must be less than or equal to maximum corner"' no se cumple.
Abortado (`core' generado)
```

[image: rviz terminal output quaternion error]

I get this plugin for visualization of this type of topics: **https://github.com/Kukanani/vision_msgs_visualization**

There are some failures like this in internet but no one is useful for me.

[image: rviz ork object display]

Comment: Please copy the error message as text and not as a picture, so that other will find this question in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `orientation.w = 1` for every quaternion in the message if you don't have another orientation you want them to have. It's unfortunate that `(0, 0, 0, 1)` isn't the default value, or that rviz couldn't automatically force quaternions to be valid (and issue an error or warning) instead bringing down the whole application.

In `to_ros_boxes_3d()` in https://github.com/opendr-eu/opendr/blob/master/projects/opendr_ws/src/opendr_bridge/src/opendr_bridge/bridge.py#L769-L782 it sets the orientation of `box.bbox` but doesn't set it for `box.results[0]`- try adding `box.results[0].pose.pose.orientation.w = 1.0` (and if there were more than one `ObjectHypothesisWithPose` be sure any others have orientation.w = 1.0 (unless you know the orientation ought to be something else).

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. I'm new at ROS and I don't know how can i make this. Maybe doing **rostopic pub** and modifying the orientation value to 1 as you said? I don't know which could be the most efficient and fast way because I think that what I'm doing is only valid for once. I would appreciate any help thanks!

Comment: Are you able to modify the publisher of the Detection3D messages?  That is where the fix is needed.  Or you have to have a new node subscribe to raw Detections, fix the w value in them, then republish and have rviz subscribe to those

Comment: Yes, I can modify this file, but which should be the line I need to add to my code to fix this orientation?

Comment: In the code that creates the Detection3D- do `rosmsg show Detection3DArray` and you'll see instances of `orientation` you need to fill out

Comment: Doing this I get: **geometry_msgs/Quaternion orientation
          float64 x
          float64 y
          float64 z
          float64 w** but how can I set the value of W to 1 as you said in your answer?

Comment: Can you add the part of the code that creates the Detection3D into your question, or link to it on github?

Comment: Yes of course, is here: https://github.com/opendr-eu/opendr/tree/master/projects/opendr_ws/src/opendr_perception/scripts  the script **object_detection_3d_voxel_node.py**

Comment: Ok I updated my answer after looking at that code

Comment: Ok, finally adding **box.results[0].pose.pose.orientation.w = 1.0** where you told me solved my problem. Thanks for your time!